# Page jumps to top when I select javascript element?

Tags: jquery, slidedown

Does anybody know why it's jumping to the top when one of the bin `<div>`s is selected? I've tried everything, and it just won't work (in Chrome, at least).

Here's my script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bin1").click(function(){ 
           $("#div1").slideDown("1000"); 
           $("#div3").hide(); 
           $("#div2").hide();  
           $("#div4").hide();
        });
       $("#bin2").click(function(){ 
           $("#div2").slideDown("1000"); 
           $("#div3").hide(); 
           $("#div1").hide();  
           $("#div4").hide();
        });
      $("#bin3").click(function(){ 
          $("#div3").slideDown("1000"); 
           $("#div1").hide(); 
           $("#div2").hide();  
           $("#div4").hide();
       });
     $("#bin4").click(function(){ 
          $("#div4").slideDown("slow"); 
          $("#div3").hide(); 
          $("#div2").hide();  
          $("#div1").hide();

          return false;
      });
  });
 </script>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="binheader" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <a href="javascript: return null;" id="bin1">
    <img src="img/black bin name.png"
    style="width:200px; float:left;" />
  </a>
  <a href="javascript: return null;" id="bin2">
    <img src="img/green bin name.png"
    style="padding-left:33px; width:200px; float:left;" />
  </a>
  <a href="javascript: return null;" id="bin3">
    <img src="img/yellow box name.png"
    style="padding-left: 34px; width:200px; float:left;" />
  </a>
  <a href="javascript: return null;" id="bin4">
    <img src="img/green box name.png"
    style="padding-left:33px; width:200px; float:left;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are those #divX elements inside a UL list or something? That could make your code simpler: `$('#divs > li').hide().eq(i).slideDown();`

Comment: Please prefer `<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();" id="bin4">` instead.

Comment: @meagar The OP already has click handlers defined for those anchors. He should place `event.preventDefault();` or just  `return false;` at the end of those click handlers. Setting onevent attributes, ergo, placing JavaScript code inside the markup, should be avoided.

Comment: @Šime I agree completely, I didn't mean to suggest adding an inline onclick attributes to every link. The detail I could include in a comment was limited.

Answer (score 7):

```
<a id="bin1" href="#">
```

and then in the click handler:

```
$('#bin1').click(function() {
    // do stuff
    return false;
});
```

Your page jumps to the top because your code - `href="javascript: return null;"` - fails to disable the anchors. Don't put JavaScript code inside the `href` attribute!

---

***Consider this...***

HTML:

```
<ul id="links">
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="..."> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="..."> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="..."> </a> </li>
</ul>

<ul id="slides">
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#links a').click(function() {
   var i = $(this).parent().index();
   $('#slides').children().hide().eq(i).slideDown('slow');
});
```

Note that I shortened your 24 lines of code to just 4 lines!

Comment: You [shouldn't use](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) `return false;` unless you actually need it.

Comment: @Tgr Or... You should't bother with `e.preventDefault()` unless you actually need the event propagation.

Comment: That hasn't worked - I've done this:
$("#bin1").click(function(){ 
           $("#div1").slideDown("1000"); 
           $("#div3").hide(); 
           $("#div2").hide();  
           $("#div4").hide();
           return false;
        });

And on the HTML I've done this:
<a href="#" id="bin1">

Any more ideas?

Comment: @Jamie You probably got an error which prevents the JavaScript code from executing. Check the error console in your browser ...

Comment: I've replaced it with Fade - that doesn't jump it, so it'll do.